# How to add request timeout or connection timeout in traditional spring mvc application to prevent ''slow http post vulnerability"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, wildfly-10

There are following points to make you understand about my application:

1. I have a traditional spring web application running on Wild-fly.
2. In my application I have view controller and other controllers.
3. I have web.xml file and jboss xml file to configure context path.
4. Request to controller comes through either ajax request or simple get 
   request from browser.

I want to keep safe my application from possible 'Slow HTTP Post Vulnerability'. For that I have decided if any request takes more than specified amount of time then my application release that connection and throw request time-out exception.

My question is :
How can I implement request time in traditional spring mvc application ?

Note : You are most welcome If you have any other solution to prevent 'slow HTTP post vulnerability'.

Answer (score 0):

You could delegate each controller invocation to a separate thread and then monitor that thread if/until it breaches your timeout condition. Java's `ExecutorService` already supports something much like this with its `awaitTermination()` feature.

Using Spring's support for asynchronous controllers (or more generally; implementing non blocking services) would formalise this approach since (a) it would *force* you to delegate your controller invocations to a separate threadpool and (b) it would encourage you to safely manage the resources available in this threadpool. More details on this approach [here](http://www.xpadro.com/2015/07/understanding-callable-and-spring.html) and [here](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/09/09/asynchronous-spring-service/).

But, however you perform this delegation once you have each controller invocation running in a separate thread (separate from the original invocation, I mean) you will then be able to control how long that thread can run and if it exceeds some configured timeout you can respond with a relevant [HTTP status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).